# Formatting object for console.log() in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, console

Anybody have any ideas about formatting an object/DOM element passed to console.log() in IE, so that it actually makes sense? I can't add it to script > watch because I need a snapshot of the object when it is logged to the console.

Given a DOM element, for example:

```
<div id="outter"><span id="inner">test</span><p></p></div>
```

Doing:

```
console.log( document.getElementById('outter') );
// results in:
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

Doing:

```
console.log( JSON.stringify( document.getElementById('outter') ) );
// results in:
{}
```

Doing this directly in the developer console:

```
document.getElementById('outter')
// results in:
[object HTMLDivElement] {
    align : "",
    noWrap : false,
    dataFld : "",
    dataFormatAs : "",
    dataSrc : "",
    currentStyle : [object MSCurrentStyleCSSProperties],
    runtimeStyle : [object MSStyleCSSProperties],
    accessKey : "",
    classList : ,
    className : ""
    ...
}
```

Doing**:

```
console.log( $('#outter') );
// results in:
[object Object]
```

Doing**:

```
console.log( JSON.stringify( $('#outter') ) );
// results in:
{"0":{},"length":1,"context":{},"selector":"#outter"}
```

Ideally I would like something along the lines of what firebug does but something simplified would do. I can't use firebug-lite because of compatibility problems I'm having with it.

** I have used a jQuery object here but it could be any "complex" object in javascript that could contain a reference to a DOM object, or not.

Comment: Have you tried _console.dir()_?

Comment: @nnnnnn Nice try but have you seen what your console looks like when you do console.dir( document.getElementById('outter') ); I am looking for something that you can actually work with - if I could collapse that list of 100+ properties like you can do in script > watch then we're talking.